# How to know that if a table is empty or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a custom management system with php & mysql and till now I have made the admin panel for inserting posts into the site template but I want to show the users that if the table of `blog_posts` is empty ,echo out *empty* for example & if not then retrieve the data of table & show them to users.

Here's my **blog_posts.php** page which shows the posts of the table to users:

```
<div id="box">
  <div class="BJadidBold">
    <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $content; ?></p></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this my **php_parsers.php** which I have included it:

```
$select_posts = "select * from posts";
$run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$select_posts);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){
    $id = $row['post_id'];
    $title = $row['post_title'];
    $date = $row['post_date'];
    $author = $row['post_author'];
    $image = $row['post_image'];
    $keywords = $row['post_keywords'];
    $content = $row['post_content'];
}
```

When I have not inserted any posts from my admin panel ,the blog_posts page will show this notice:

> undefined variable: title ...

How to know whether the table is empty or not & if it's empty do something else instead of printing data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$select_posts = "select * from posts";     $run_posts = mysqli_query($con,$select_posts);
if (mysqli_num_rows($run_posts) > 0)   {     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)){ 
$id = $row['post_id'];
 $title =     $row['post_title']; 
$date = $row['post_date']; 
$author = $row['post_author'];
$image = $row['post_image']; 
$keywords = $row['post_keywords']; 
$content =    $row['post_content']; }
}else{
echo"No Posts";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Befor your $select_posts query insert these lines of codes

`$num_rows=mysqli_query("select count(*)as total from posts ");`
`$tot_rows=mysqli_fetch_array(total);`
`if($tot_rows['total']<1){`
`echo "No Post Found ";`
`}`
`else{`

`Your fetch query here`

`}`

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_num_rows() directly after querying the table to determine if you return any posts or not.

```
$totalrows = mysqli_num_rows($run_posts);
```

with 'if' statement you can give user a message or list of rows. To avoid the error do not go into 'while' statement until you find something, otherwise you need to make all variables = null to avoid the undefined warning.